# left shift magic

Tags: c++, c

I have code:

```
signed short a = -32740;
float c;
float b;
b = (signed short)(a << 4);
c = a << 4;
printf("(signed short)(a << 4): %f\n", b);
printf("(a << 4): %f\n", c);
```

output:

```
(signed short)(a << 4): 448.000000
(a << 4): -523840.000000
```

Why 16 senior registers not reset after the shift (`c = a << 4;`)?

Program executed on x86 machine with 32-bit linux.

Comment: Do you mean `float c` where you wrote `float a`? And what are "senior registers"?

Comment: Did you compile it?. -1 for not compiling it, testing it, **before** posting !

Comment: Integer type promotions.

Comment: "Do you mean float c where you wrote float a?" - fixed. Copied from a laptop, where i compile it.

Comment: `-1` removed, as the question is corrected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> b = (signed short)(a << 4);

This line does the following:

1. Calculate (a << 4). The calculation is done with integers (default in C). The result is: -523840
2. Truncate the result (by dropping bits) to 16 bit by casting to signed short. (result is 448)
3. convert the result to float (no change in value)

> c = a << 4;

This line does the following:

1. Calculate (a << 4). The calculation is done with integers (default in C). The result is: -523840
2. convert the result to float (no change in value)

The fact that 'a' is declared as a signed short does not make a difference because all calculations are always done with the int datatype. I assume that your system has 32 bit integers.

Comment: Does it means that where is no operator like `short operator <<(short, short);` ?

Comment: In effect, yes; there is no shift operator that works on short integers.

Comment: The compiler will either and or shift off the high 16-bits when you place this into the short.

Comment: @nick: Overflow of signed quantities results in UB, so if there were a short version of `<<` it would not do what you want in this case either...